# How can I quickly switch between two out of multiple languages?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support, input-language

I have 3 input sources (languages) configured in Text Input Settings. Let us call them E (as in English) and A and B for two other languages. Mainly I switching between English and A or English and B and almost never between A and B. However switching keyboard shortcuts always cycle them in E->A->B or E<-A<-B direction. This is very inconvenient.

I am looking for a way to do this as it is implemented under MacOS, where switcher cycles between the 2 last languages by default, but you can force it to advance to 3rd one using a separate shortcut or via toolbar menu, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Is it possible to configure something like this on Ubuntu?

EDIT:
Jacob's solution below allows to create a custom shortcut to switch between two languages. I've modified his script to replicate MacOS switching scheme, where last 2 languages are cycles automatically. You can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/vzaliva/63cb29b100e9d24f3070c2b78c98d6e4). Blog post explaining details [here](http://lambda-files.crocodile.org/2017/01/switching-between-3-languages-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: So basically, what you need is a shortcut to toggle between two languages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcuts for each input language](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690539/keyboard-shortcuts-for-each-input-language)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson close, but not exactly. OP wants *one* shortcut to toggle, not multiple to control multiple languages.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: True. I thought it was close enough, but now I see that you wrote an answer which provides exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: One caveat: The screenshot above does not look like Unity. Hopefully the OP is using a flavor which makes use of the same gsettings schema as Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @krokodil, there is one downside in using /dev/shm, see my edited answer.

Comment: See my answer to the same question at https://askubuntu.com/a/1297902/363976.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Toggle between two (fixed) languages

What you describe is basically a keyboard shortcut to toggle between two input languages. The script below will offer the option.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
k = ["org.gnome.desktop.input-sources", "current"]

def get(command):  return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8")

currlang = get(["gsettings", "get", k[0], k[1]]).strip().split()[-1]
newlang = args[1] if currlang == args[0] else args[0]
subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", k[0], k[1], newlang])
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_lang.py`
2. In a terminal window, run the command:

   ```
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
   ```

   This will output like:

   ```
   [('xkb', 'us+intl'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'nl')]
   ```

   This list represents your input languages. The *index* of the languages is equal to the position in the list, starting with `0`, e.g. `('xkb', 'us')` has *index* 1 (in my case).
3. Now test-run the script to toggle between two indexes. To toggle between `('xkb', 'us+intl')` and `('xkb', 'nl')` (index `0` and `2`):

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_lang.py 1 3
   ```

   where bot languages are represented by the arguments

   ```
   1 3
   ```
4. If all works fine, add it to a shortut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_lang.py 1 3
   ```

   to a shortcut of your choice.

You can then use the existing shortcut to browse *all* languages, or (of course) the menu.

#### Short explanation

- The available languages can be retrieved by the command:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
  ```
- The *currently set* language can be retrieved by the command:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current
  ```

  which will output (a.o.) the *index* of the currently set language.
- We can *set* the language by (e.g.) the command:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
  ```

  to set the language to the first in the list (index 0)

In short: if we run the script we two languages (indices) as arguments, the script will look what is the current index, will switch to the other one.

---

### 2. Toggle between the two last used languages

The version of the script below will switch between *the two last used* languages, which turned out to be similar to the behaviour of MacOs.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

k = ["org.gnome.desktop.input-sources", "current"]
stored = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".lastlang")

def get(command):  return subprocess.check_output(command).decode("utf-8")

currlang = get(["gsettings", "get", k[0], k[1]]).strip().split()[-1]
try:
    newlang = open(stored).read().strip()
except FileNotFoundError:
    newlang = currlang

open(stored, "wt").write(currlang)
subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", k[0], k[1], newlang])
```

I added this version as an additional option. The two last used languages will persist (be remembered) after reboot.

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `switchlang.py`
2. Test- run the script by the command:

   ```
   python3/ path/to/switchlang.py
   ```

   After first run, switch language from the menu, now run

   ```
   python3/ path/to/switchlang.py
   ```

   again. From then on, the script will always toggle between the last two used languages.

Comment: Thanks for the script! I am about to try it. I tried commands from your explanation and last one does not work. You missed 'current' before 0

Comment: @krokodil ah, you are right! Thanks. Luckily the script includes it :) (edited)

Comment: Thanks for your script. It is almost what I asked. I have to tweak it a bit to reproduce MacOS behaviour I am after. Here is my version: https://gist.github.com/vzaliva/63cb29b100e9d24f3070c2b78c98d6e4

Comment: Hi @krokodil the only downside of the linked version is that it uses `/dev/shm` (`tmpfs`): https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html, which will not persist after reboot; it uses virtual memory (I tried and indeed it doesn't). I therefore added the version in the edited answer.

Comment: thanks. I intentionally used shm as I think this setting should not persist during reboot. I also wanted to keep it all in memory to avoid even a chance of spinning disks. It now occured to me that I might as well use ENV to store last state. I am going to test this theory. Also, I think in my script error handling is better. It will still switch language even if it could not write, and it will default to language 0 if it could not read. I

Comment: @krokodil I see, but why would you default to 0, and not persist? Anyway, always nice if the next user can pick whatever he or she likes. Now three options. Thanks!.

Comment: +1 for the idea and the script. Instead of invoking the `gsettings` program you could also access GSettings through the GIO bindings in Python. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/85162/how-can-i-change-the-wallpaper-using-a-python-script for an example.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks! I know, I believe Serg is using that usually. I prefer simply using subprocess though; it is much shorter and does not require additional imports (apart from subprocess of course :) )

Answer (score 2):

Go:  >System Settings > Text Entry

```
  and add languages to "Input sources to use:"
```

[image]

make sure to check "Show current input source in menu bar" just select input sources from the drop down menu.

Comment: This is the most simplistic and helpful explanation for solving the issue I've found so far on AskUbuntu, using Ub 16.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In recent Ubuntu versions with the default GNOME desktop, it works exactly like that (at least in my case with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut). But in Unity desktop, it's still a problem...

The workaround for Unity is to use ibus switcher which provides the MRU-switching functionality out of the box. It is used by Unity and installed along with it by default usually. (If not, install it and set it at System Settings -> Language Support -> Keyboard input method system.)

You can configure it with `ibus-setup` gui (run from terminal):

1. in the Advanced tab uncheck 'Use system keyboard layout';
2. add your languages in the 'Input Method' tab;
3. add your switching shortcut in the 'General' tab.

Now, delete the shortcuts in Unity's config at System Settings -> Text Entry and untick 'Show current input source in the menu bar' (it won't work with ibus switcher anyway).

Now you all set and it should work. If you could not find your language in ibus (like it happened to me with English (UK)) - you can manually add it easily, check the workaround here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1540587.

One more last thing: ibus has its own indicator, but it’s ugly and it does not show up in Unity’s menu bar anyway, so if you want to see the current language indicator – try gxkb. It will show a nice country flag of your current language. (You can add gxkb to Startup Applications to start automatically on login.)