# Switching between several languages using keyboard shortcut

Tags: scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I use multiple (N) keyboard mappings (languages) and it's confusing and time-consuming to switch between languages the standard way - pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> several times (up to N-1) until I get the right language.

Is there a way in the current user interface (or [by a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871678/how-can-i-quickly-switch-between-two-out-of-multiple-languages)) to make the switching easier to remember, faster, less prone to mistakes?

For example, if I (mentally) order the languages this way:

1. English
2. French
3. Russian

.... then I want to have something like the following shortcuts:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for English

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for French

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for Russian

So whatever language the current one is, I will know immediately how to switch to a different one.

Comment: Super+1,2 and 3 are used to activate the 1st 3 icons on the launcher when using Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind it's just an example; I am looking for some fixed prefix + number.

Comment: My, oh, my, I think this answer shows how to accomplish such a miracle https://askubuntu.com/questions/690539/keyboard-shortcuts-for-each-input-language