# How not to cycle between two most recent languages in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, language-support

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and GNOME as my desktop environment. The behaviour I would like to achieve is each time I switch language I go to the next one, but for some reason it changed lately to just switching between two last languages. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871678/how-can-i-quickly-switch-between-two-out-of-multiple-languages) question describes the opposite problem, I need functionality from which this post gets rid of.